# Does TFS have a "Github/Milestone" or "JIRA/Version" functionality?

Tags: github, tfs, jira, project-management

We are using TFS 2017 as our project management system, and I'm missing a functionality that seems to be available in most other solutions: it's the ability to regroup tasks/user stories/bugs/etc into a single set (called [Milestone](https://help.github.com/articles/about-milestones/) in Github, or [Version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/planning-a-version) in JIRA) to be able to track the work done and remaining for the release of a defined set of functionalities.

Does TFS provides an equivalent to those Milestones/Versions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a [sprint / iteration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/sprint-planning) to me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but as the sprint is a development period, it's not the real equivalent to milestones: in a same sprint, you can work on multiple milestones.
I'm looking for a tool that would regroup items per functionalities/release more than by period of working time.

Answer (score 1):

Since Iteration path is hierarchical you can create nodes that represent Releases or Milestones (versions are a bad idea) and then have your Working Time as Sprints under them.

Release 1
Release 1\Sprint 1
Release 1\Sprint 2
Release 1\Sprint 3
Release 1\Sprint 4
release 2
Release 2\Sprint 1

You can then have a variable number of Sprints inside of each Release. If you are in VSTS you get good visual planning tools to help you plan across releases or sprints...

Another options would be to add a custom field for the data that you want to track.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Iterations is typically the way to go.  However, you can also use [Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=vsts) and [Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/example-queries?view=vsts) to create release or milestone lists that are either flat or hierarchical.  If the queries are flat, you can create [graphs/charts and dashboard them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=vsts) as well.

[Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) also add yet another alternative to help visualize timelines and create markers for important dates/milestones.